# Converting a decimal into a fraction

Tags: c, rational-numbers

I have written a small program that converts a decimal number into a reduced fraction representation. I also designed this little program to be fairly robust, so that it can give the correct output for various inputs.

For example:

> ```
> ./a.out 3,000.375
> 24003/8
> ./a.out "3 000,375"
> 24003/8
> ./a.out 3.000,375
> 24003/8
> ./a.out 3000.375
> 24003/8
> ```

Here is the complete code for the program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int isDigit(char);
void simplify(unsigned long long *, unsigned long long *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Please enter a number to fractionize.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    char *input = argv[1];
    int i;
    char c;
    unsigned long long previous, denominator = 1, numerator = 0;
    for (i = strlen(input) - 1; i >= 0; i--, denominator *= 10) {
        c = input[i];
        if (!isDigit(c)) {
            break;
        }
        previous = numerator;
        numerator = (c - '0') * denominator + numerator;
        if (previous > numerator) {
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    if (c == '-' || isDigit(c)) {
        printf("%llu/1\n", numerator);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    simplify(&numerator, &denominator);
    int j, negative = 0;
    unsigned long long whole = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        char c = input[j];
        if (c == '-') {
            negative = 1;
        } else if (isDigit(c)) {
            previous = whole;
            whole = whole * 10 + (c - '0');
            if (previous > whole) {
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
    }
    previous = numerator;
    numerator += whole * denominator;
    if (previous > numerator) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    simplify(&numerator, &denominator);
    if (negative) {
        printf("-");
    }
    printf("%llu/%llu\n", numerator, denominator);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int isDigit(char c) {
    return c >= '0' && c <= '9';
}

void simplify(unsigned long long *numerator, unsigned long long *denominator) {
    while (1) {
        if ((*numerator % 2 == 0) && (*denominator % 2 == 0)) {
            *numerator   /= 2;
            *denominator /= 2;
        } else if ((*numerator % 5 == 0) && (*denominator % 5 == 0)) {
            *numerator   /= 5;
            *denominator /= 5;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

My algorithm is basically to first process the number right to left. As soon as a non-digit is detected, the part of the input that has been processed is deemed the "fractional part". This fractional part is then simplified (when possible). For example `"12.34"` would be processed as `34` and `100`, which would then be simplified to `17` and `50`.

Then, the input is processed left to right up to the point where the first scan terminated. Any non-digit characters are ignored (except the minus sign), and digits are accumulated (`12` in this case). This is deemed the "whole part".

Then, the whole part is multiplied by the (simplified) denominator and it is added to the (simplified) fractional part (in this case, the fraction would be `617` over `50`). The fraction is then again simplified (when possible) and the result is printed out.

My main concern is how I handle overflow. Because I am using `unsigned` types, overflow would simply cause the number to wrap around towards 0, so I simply check if the number before the computation (stored in `previous`) is larger than the number after the computation. If it is, then overflow has occurred. This seems like a fairly naive way to do it, but it seems to work for the inputs that I have tried.

Otherwise, any stylistic or performance-related inputs are always appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're being too lenient with your input checking, which results in some unexpected results:

> -3,000,0    results in:     -3000/1
>
> 3,000      results in: 3/1
>
> 3 results in 3/1
>
> 3-1 results in 1/1

Personally, I'd pick an expected format and then ensure that the input complies with it.  If you want to support multiple [decimal marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark), then I would suggest having a function for each supported format that validates the input and returns it in one common format which is then used by the rest of the code.

**argc & argv**

In your example you have `./a.out "3 000,375"`.  You're quoting the space in order to ensure it's all pushed as part of `argv[1]`.  It seems likely that this could be forgotten.  If it was, then you would end up with the output of `3/1`.  Your `argc` checking only checks for no parameters being supplied:

```
if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Please enter a number to fractionize.\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Unless you're going to continue through the arguments supplied, appending them to the input it would be better to do something like this:

```
if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <number to fractionize>\n", argv[0]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

**One declaration per line**

This is obviously subjective, but I don't particularly like multiple declarations on a single line.  I don't mind it so much when you're declaring several uninitialised variables, however when you're assigning values to the variables it would be better to have each declaration on a new line.  For me, denominator and previous get a bit lost on this line:

```
unsigned long long previous, denominator = 1, numerator = 0;
```

Comment: Regarding the quoting problem: I'd just pass the input via `stdin`. This I think is far easier and more logic.

Answer (score 6):

1. The `simplify()` works, but to offer a quick and more general approach, find the `gcd()` with  [Euclid's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).  The following is not specialized for 2 and 5.

   ```
   unsigned long long gcd_ull(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b) {
     while (b) {
       a %= b;
       if (a == 0) return b;
       b %= a;
     }
     return a;
   }

   void simplify(unsigned long long *num, unsigned long long *den) {
     unsigned long long gcd = gcd_ull(*num, *dem);
     if (gcd) {
       *num /= gcd;
       *dem /= gcd;
     }
   }
   ```
2. It's unclear why code uses `unsigned long long`.  Use `unsigned` for quickness.  Use `uintmax_t` for maximum width without resorting to more elaborate code.
3. **Overflow protection**: use basic overflow protection, to ensure that the math does not overflow.  `if (previous > whole) {` approach will detect *some* overflow, but not all.

   ```
   // whole = whole * 10 + (c - '0');
   if (whole >= ULLONG_MAX/10 && 
       (whole > ULLONG_MAX/10 || (c-'0') > ULLONG_MAX%10)) {
     Overflow();
   } else {
     whole = whole * 10 + (c - '0');
   }
   ```
4. `simplify()` attempts `/0` should `*numerator == 0`.  Use #1
5. `if (argc != 2) {` would be a stronger test than `argc < 2` to detect an unexpected parameter count.
6. Lack of overflow protection on `denominator *= 10` which occurs when `whole` is large like `18446744073709551615` or `input` has lots of leading zeros like `"0.000000000000000000001"`.
7. I recommend a new approach for a robust solution.  In theory, select text input with 64 significant decimal digits could have a representable answer as a `unsigned long long`.  TBD a good solution - which I suspect would be entirely text based.

Answer (score 3):

Your use of descriptive variable names and function names is good.

**Main is too long**
Your main() function contains too much code which makes it difficult to maintain. You have code for at least 2 more functions in main(). Both of the for loops are good candidates for functions. A well written function performs one and only one action.

**Define functions before use**
If you define your functions before you use them in main() you don't need these declarations at the top of the file.

```
int isDigit(char);
void simplify(unsigned long long *, unsigned long long *);
```

In the long run these definitions could be maintenance problems if you need to change the parameters to the functions. The way your code is written to add a parameter to a function you need to do it in 2 different locations. A good habit might be to make main() the last function in the file.

As your programs get more complex, you may have multiple files. You may want to reuse a function name in another file. To make you functions local only to the file:

```
static int isDigit(char) {
    return c >= '0' && c <= '9';
}
static void simplify(unsigned long long *, unsigned long long *)  {
    while (1) {
        if ((*numerator % 2 == 0) && (*denominator % 2 == 0)) {
            *numerator   /= 2;
            *denominator /= 2;
        } else if ((*numerator % 5 == 0) && (*denominator % 5 == 0)) {
            *numerator   /= 5;
            *denominator /= 5;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `uint64_t` from `stdint.h` instead of writing out `unsigned long long`.  Shorter yet same (if not more) meaning.

Comment: Can you clarify your last comment, checking against primes? Since the denominator is always a multiple of ten, its only prime factors will be 2 and/or 5. How can I improve that code by checking "against the first twenty primes"?

Comment: @MartinTuskevicius I have removed that part of my answer. You're correct it will always be a multiple of 10.

Comment: I don't agree that `main()` should be the last function -- this is personal preference imho. I prefer to be structure my code the way that I can read it from top to bottom, just like a book.

Comment: @syb0rg `unsigned long long` may be wider than `uint64_t`.  On rare machines, `uint64_t` is not available on compliant C platforms.

Comment: @chux Those would have to be old machines (ones that adhere only to the C89 standards), correct?

Comment: @syb0rg  Concerning old machines using non-2's complement (uncommon but not non-existent) may be C11 compliant.  "`uintN_t` ... These types are optional."  on such machines.  See C11dr §7.20.1.1 for greater detail.